# Changing the position of a UITextView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I have looked at a lot of posts and did several searches but haven't found an answer.  Maybe there isn't one.  I have added a UIText View to my view but I would like to move it down so it appears about half way down the page.

Comment: Iphone? By the look of the class I guess you may be talking about an Iphone app. Am I right?

Comment: yes, I am building an iphone app and want a imageview at the top and text view at the bottom.  But I don't want to use IB.

Comment: I see that you edited this about four minutes ago Mihai but I don't see it?

Comment: Retagged, such that more developers can answer

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `frame` property of either the `UITextView` or `UIImageView` and set their position with it.

ex.

```
myUITextView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);
```

Answer (score 1):

for image view:

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 100, 50)];
```

for text :

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[textView setFrame:CGRectMake(X, Y, 320.0, 200)];
[textView setEditable:NO];

[self addSubview:imgView];
[self addSubview:textView];
```

Comment: Thanks that did it.  Is there anyway to make the text noneditable?

Comment: Click the arrow under this post, on the left. (I think it's right below the arrows). Its looks like a " check box " 's sign

Answer (score 0):

Create it in a frame. I cannot test the code here but you should do something like

1. get the required frame where you want to put the widget
2. create the widget using the `initWithFrame` constructor

That is:

```
/* 1. */
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(cornerX, cornerY, width, height);
/* 2. */
UITextView *tw = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame: frame];
```

Hope it works and it's useful.

Comment: this is what I have,    - (void)setupTextView
{
  
    self.textView = [[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame] autorelease];
    self.textView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:18.0];
    self.textView.delegate = self;
    self.textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    
    self.textView.text = @"Location One etc.";
   
    self.textView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    
       [self.view addSubview: self.textView];
}  Where would I put the CGRect frame?

Comment: `self.textView = [[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:__HERE__] autorelease]`

I've marked the spot with `__HERE__`

Answer (score 0):

Try Creating view like this with the proper coordinates.

```
UITextView *textView = [[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGFloat x, CGFloat y,CGFloat width, CGFloat height) autorelease];
```