# How to push uitextview up so not hindered by keyboard?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Anyone knows?

Sometimes some Uitextview is way below the screen. You pop the keyboard and that uitextview is hidden by the keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try detecting when the keyboard is displayed and if it is, move the UITextView - a way to move a UITextView is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6743517/187954